# Java Servlet + TomCat - Не удается передать данные

Tags: java, servlet

Начал изучать сервлеты и возникла следующая проблема. Имеется:

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Словарь</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Введите слово:
  <form method="post" action="/">
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="word"></label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="ok"><br>
  </form>
  <c:out value = "${requestScope.getText}" default="null"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

StartPage.java

```
public class StartPage extends HttpServlet {

private String text;
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("doget");
   req.setAttribute("getText", text);
   req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp);


}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("doPost");
    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    final String word = req.getParameter("word");
    text = word;
    System.out.println(word);
    doGet(req, resp);
}

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {

    System.out.println("init");
}
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StartPage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.StartPage</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StartPage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SecondPage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.Second</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SecondPage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/second</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Пытаюсь передать данные с формы в сервлет и вернуть обратно на index.jsp. Код второго сервлета не привожу, в него данные передаются без проблем. Но как только меняю

```
<form method="post" action="/second">
```

на

```
<form method="post" action="/">
```

при нажатии на форму метод doPost не отрабатывает. Вместо него вызывается doGet.
Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените имя index.jsp на любое другое и все должно заработать.
У меня совсем из головы вылетело что всегда любой сервер сначала ищет index файл.

Да ище одно. Если вы наследуетесь от HttpServlet то метод init переопределять ненужно.

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо